# Is this a bug in visual studio 2019? I'm getting a error CS0570 for a program while debugging

Tags: c#, default-interface-member

Consider the following interface and a dummy class that implements it.

```
interface I<out T>
{
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> M()
    {
        var x = default(T);
        yield return x;
    }
}

public class C : I<string>
{
    public static void Main() => System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(((I<string>)new C()).M());
}
```

now put a breakpoint on line 6 (yield return x).
Execute the program and you'll notice something odd if you try to watch x, It tells you the following:

> error CS0570: '<>x.<>m0(I.d__0)' is not supported by the language

Obviously, the program works so it is supported by the language, but the debugger has no idea what to do with it.
This also happens for `async` (`Task{T}`,`ValueTask{T}`, or `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`) returning methods.

Before the usual stream of comments, this is **NOT** my actualcode. I have an actual valid use case for using a default interface member (interface versioning), my actual method is more complicated and calls other members of the interface, but the dim is a generator method in the and debugging a poorly compliant implementer is a nightmare, and I've essentially had to resort to log messages.

Comment: Yes, this seems like an IDE / debugger limitation. Perhaps worth reporting : Help -> Send Feedback -> Report a Problem. Maybe test it with the preview IDE first, of course.

Comment: FYI, when I execute it, I never hit the breakpoint you set, instead I get an exception at line 12 (`Enumerable.Any`)... **System.TypeLoadException**: 'Could not load type '<M>d__0' from assembly 'ConsoleApp1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it declares a covariant or contravariant type parameter and is not an interface or delegate.' This is on VS2019 version 16.4.4.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39731) might be related.